# How to save cloudinary url to mongoDb

Tags: node.js, express, cloudinary

I'm trying to save Cloudinary url to MongoDB but really don't know what is wrong with my code, because it's not working.

here is my code :

```
exports.test = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const email = req.params.email;
  console.log

  cloudinary.uploader
    .upload(req.file.path, { folder: 'avatar' })
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);// shows correctly on console
      const { secure_url, public_id } = result;
      console.log('url:',secure_url)// url & secure_url shows correctly on console
      console.log('public_url:',public_id);
      
      Resume.findOneAndUpdate(
       
        {
          email:email,
        },
        { $set: { imagePath: secure_url} },      
        {
          new: true,
          fields: {
            imagePath: 1,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log('upload successful!!');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  
});
```

I use $set because I want the field created if it didn't exist before. Also, I get the public_id and secure_url successfully from Cloudinary, but it didn't save in my database.

here is the output from console.log(result):

```
{
asset_id: '1ee919b68e258c9778097e40671ac710',
public_id: 'seawedkarowxgnipz8hq',
url: 'http://res.cloudinary.com/workaman/image/upload/v1656322947/seawedkarowxgnipz8hq.png',
secure_url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/workaman/image/upload/v1656322947/seawedkarowxgnipz8hq.png',
original_filename: 'file_cuyajt',

 }
```

and here is how i defined the model:

```
const ResumeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

      imagePath:{
        type:String,
        required:false
    },
      cloudinary_Id:{
        type:String,
        required:false
    },
})
```

It seems I'm missing out on something but I really can't figure it out. when I submit from the frontend, I get the message "console.log('upload successfully!!')"  but nothing is saved.

Comment: I don't see any insert calls to your MongoDB, perhaps https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/insert/ will help, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you're mixing up the MongoDB Node.js SDK with Mongoose a little bit. In the code that you shared you have both `ResumeSchema` and `Resume` - just check that those are correct.

In Mongoose the [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) method does not have a `$set` option. The [MongoDB CLI](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) and subsequently their [Node.js Driver](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/updateOne/) also has `findOneAndUpdate()`, but the signature of that function and it's usage options somewhat differ.

Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to tell what is exactly going on but my gut feeling is that you've mixed up these two methods. I hope this helps.